# dtype changes after set_value/at

Tags: python, pandas

I'm facing a weird issue on Pandas now, not sure if a pandas pitfall or just something I'm missing...

My pd.Series is just

`foo
False
False
False`

`> a.foo.dtype
dtype('bool')`

When I use a `dataframe.set_value(index, col, None)`, my whole Series is converted to `dtype('float64')` (same thing applies to `a.at[index, col] = None`).

Now my Series is

`foo
NaN
NaN
NaN`

Do you have any idea on how this happens and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance. :)

Edit:
Using 0.20.1.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on `0.22`.

Comment: Added pandas version. Using 0.20.1.

Comment: What are the values of `index` and `col`?

Comment: In this case, col is `foo`, index  would be the MultiIndex object (dataframe.index).

Comment: That is important. Can you please attempt to reproduce this with some data sample?

Comment: Set another series as False (`a.Bar = False`) and applied set_value on this series as well. Same issue, converted to NaN (dtype from bool to float64).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is related to the fact that I was trying to assign a `None` to a `bool` Series, then it just tries to convert to a different type (why not object?)

Fixed changing the dtype to `object` first: `dataframe.foo = dataframe.foo.astype(object)`.

Works like a charm now.